# how to add text between two images

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm new in latex, and I don't know how to make text between the two images I try, but it doesn't work

[image]

I want the text to be between the A and B images

here what I want to make [image]

here my try :

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    
    \begin{tabular}{m{10cm} m{1cm} m{3cm}}
    
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        \includegraphics[width=45mm]{images/style/jakai.PNG} & & \vspace{1.52mm}
        \centering \large{Universite de Kairouan ´Institut Superieur ´ d’informatique et de Gestion }
        \includegraphics[width=45mm]{images/style/isiglogo.PNG}  \\
        
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think you may have put the ampersand in the wrong place. If it's a tabular then you should have "Graphic & text & Graphic \\" but you have "Graphic & & text Graphic \\".

Comment: how can I solve this problem ?? I try to edit a template

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvn64.png Probably a sketch of the expected output would help in order to clarify your question. Could you add such a sketch?

Comment: Yes just like that friend :D

Comment: I add image what I want to make exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want that the textual part is centered notwithstanding that the two images have different widths. In the image below the effect might seem wrong, but in your case the image on the right has no border and this “unbalanced effect” will not appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Université de Karouan \\
  Institut Supérieur \\
  d'Informatique et de \\
  Gestion
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the picture I added `\usepackage{showframe}` to see the line in context with the page frame.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,valign=c]{images/style/jakai.PNG}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering Universite de Kairouan 

 Institut Superieur d’informatique et de Gestion 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,valign=c]{images/style/isiglogo.PNG}

\end{document}
```